# How to trigger parse-server to create text index?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

A text query request on my [parse-server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server)

```
curl -X GET \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ${APPLICATION_ID}" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: ${REST_API_KEY}" \
  -G \
  --data-urlencode 'where={"name":{"$text":{"$search":{"$term":"Milk"}}}}' \
  --data-urlencode 'order="$score"' \
  --data-urlencode 'key="$score"' \
  http://localhost:1337/parse/classes/Groceries
```

Returns this error:

```
{"code":1,"error":{"name":"MongoError","message":"text index required for $text query","ok":0,"errmsg":"text index required for $text query","code":27,"codeName":"IndexNotFound"}}
```

What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://docs.parseplatform.org/parse-server/guide/:

> When using MongoDB with your Parse app, you need to manage your indexes yourself. You will also need to size up your database as your data grows.

"yourself" in this context means you need to connect to the mongodb with your client of choice and [create the index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index). Something like:

```
db.collection.createIndex(
   {
     field1: "text",
     field2: "text",
     etc...         
   }
)
```

Comment: where I can place this code.I checked in server.js but there is `db` object or instance found.

Comment: @KishorPatidar "you client of choice" can be mongo shell, compass, robomongo, etc.